# Syntax Error adding extra field to INSERT Query with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Morning all.  When an operator replaces a tool in a large production machine he goes to a PC and fills out information on a program I created.  Well I want to put in a timestamp when they actually log the change vs when they say they changed the tool.  The program has been in production for a few months so this is a new addition.  I created a hidden textbox and when Submit is pressed, it generates a current timestamp and is supposed to go into the database with this Query:

```
text_timestamp.Clear()
text_timestamp.Text = DateTime.Now
str = "Insert Into Log
(machine_num,change_date,change_time,timestamp,clock_num,toolnum,tool_description,cycle_num,meet_expected,change_reason,comments,inspected_by) values 
(@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d1", combo_machine.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d2", text_changedate.Value.ToShortDateString))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d3", combo_changetime.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d4", text_timestamp.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d5", text_clocknum.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d6", combo_toolnum.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d7", text_description.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d8", text_cyclenum.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d9", Meet))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d10", Reason))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d11", text_comments.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d12", text_signedoffby.Text))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()
        MsgBox("Submitted")
```

So I changed my data adapter and made sure all columns are showing up properly and it errors out at the last saying there is a syntax error in the INSERT INTO line.  It seems to only be looking for 11 lines instead of 12 because if I remove a line, no matter which, it works and I see it in my access database.  Anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong?

DataSet:

[image]

and the error in studio:

[image]

Exception Details:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException occurred
HResult=0x80040E14
Message=Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
StackTrace:
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at WindowsApp3.Form1.submit_button_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\userme\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WindowsApp3 - Copy\WindowsApp3\Form1.vb:line 134
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
at WindowsApp3.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me.  Have you logged/alerted the value of your hidden textbox to make sure its not empty?

Comment: Added my timestamp commands at the top of the OP.  Clears the field and then puts in the new stamp

Comment: Also lets say I dleete the combo_changetime line in the code, it will insert the timestamp into that field in the database so its like it only knows how to insert into 11 fields, not 12.

Comment: I still don't see anything wrong with what you've shown.  Is there a chance one of your fields has a char in it that would mess up the query? Like a single quote or a backslash or something.

Comment: I thought maybe it would but no.  Half the fields generate automatically and the others are set to be numbers only (in the code, not designer) except for the comments.

Comment: Your column name has a big `I` in Visual Studio but a small `i` in your query. Depending on the DBMS this could maybe the problem.

Comment: Just changed it and got the same results.

Comment: Can you post the exception details?

Comment: Posted at the bottom of OP

Comment: No ideas?  I still havent been able to think of anything or get it working